# How to replicate the CNN iOS app pull down menu

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Does anyone know how CNN is doing their top pull down menu?

It looks like a UITableView that is called with a touch drag event but wasn't sure. Googled various keywords but was not able to turn anything up. Just looking for some guidance on how to replicate this behavior.

[image]

Comment: is this the root controller behavior I mean can you view that menu on every view when you pull down?

Comment: There are a lot of components where one controller slides to the right revealing another one underneath. The action is initiated from the navigation controller bar, but in that screenshot it looks like you have to pull the ribbon. Anyway, learn how one of those work, then do the same top to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they are doing something like https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

You have to customize `"MFSideMenu"` a lot though. If you dont want to show this menu on every view you need to disable `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` on that view.

There is also something like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pullableview but you may need to add `UIGestureRecognizer` to this class.

Comment: Thanks SpaceDust! I think the slide out style is the same behavior I am looking for except for it coming from the horizontal I am coming vertical. Your examples provided are helpful and I am also looking at Ben Hall's examples of the slide out.  Already I am customizing it to come from the top and it's working good. https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation

Comment: you are welcome, Yes I know that you need a vertical one @Flea , thats why I suggested you to customize `"MFSideMenu" a lot` :), anyways it seems you know what you are doing, happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

I've no idea how it's actually done, but I know how I would do it: any view can sit completely or partially offscreen and be dragged onscreen by the user in the usual ways (e.g. a swipe or pan gesture recognizer). There's nothing special about that.